Does the name of a service that consists of common nouns require a definite article?
Does the name of a service that consists of common nouns require a definite article?
For example, when a company offers a service named "Quick Data Recovery Service," and I need to refer to this specific service in normal sentences, is a definite article required ("the Quick Data Recovery Service") or not ("the Quick Data Recovery Service")?
I found some sentences on a webpage of T-Mobile and think that proper noun phrases without a proper noun (composed only of common nouns) may require a definite article, but I'm not sure at all.

If you buy both the Insurance Device Protection Plan and the Service Contract Device Protection Plan, you'll get a discount of up to $1.50 on the Insurance Device Protection Plan, depending on the device tier.


In quasi-contractual texts, named services and options often use upper-case as you see  in your examples, indicating that the service or option has that name, and when the names are fitted into a sentence, determiners are added as needed.
If you're referring to the service not by the company's name for it but generically, you can paraphrase:

They offer rapid data recovery services.

But if, for example, you're instructing someone to contact them and to request the service using their name for it, you would "quote" the phrase.

Call them and tell them we need their "quick data recovery service".
Call them and tell them we need the "quick data recovery service".

In an email, say, you'd put quotation marks around the phrase, and you might also reproduce the initial upper-case letters so it matches the company's own documents. In a spoken instruction, that phrase would intoned in such a way as to indicate that you were quoting it verbatim.  That might take the form of saying the individual words with marked pauses between them:

... tell them we need their quick ... data ... recovery ... service.



Does the name of a service that consists of common nouns require a definite article?

It depends.
In your case,

If you buy both the Insurance Device Protection Plan and the Service Contract Device Protection Plan, you'll get a discount

both require a determiner of some sort (the; our; the company's, etc.) because it is a specific product/service - the one your company sells - not any other.
Furthermore, "Insurance Device Protection Plan" and "Service Contract Device Protection Plan" in the singular will always require a determiner as the head noun is countable (Plan")
(The names are very strange - are these real products? Or did you invent the name yourself?)

The article The would be used to identify the subject as a proper noun.

Not entirely true. A few proper nouns have the as part of their names, such as The Empire State building, but many do not. A proper noun identifies a particular individual or item and you wouldn't normally say "the George" or  "the Anne" . Common nouns, on the other hand, refer to a class of things cars, persons and so on. These often have a definite article.  See this Wikipedia article

For a proper answer it's also good to let others know your reasoning, and to apply it to the particulars of the question.
